# Rendering Java Android OpenGL ES on Windows

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

**Background :**

I'm currently making an Android Native game only using Java and OpenGL ES 3.0 and I wanted to make a simple Game Engine without copying my full Java project in C++ so I could have the same project on my Windows PC.

I would like to use some of my existing Java files my Android Studio Project is using, and to run them on a different window context on my PC. I would certainly make some separate Classes to set a OpenGL window and to have a `main` function.

**My questions are :**

- What API should I use to create an OpenGL context in Java?
- Will the included libraries in my Android Project Files (like `android.opengl.GLES30`) be found if I used a different IDE (like IntelliJ)?

Comment: **(1)** Always use the **latest** (highest) API. **(2)** You can use **IntelliJ IDE** if you want too, it's the base for **Android Studio** anyway.

Comment: @JonGoodwin **(1)** I was using GLFW to open a window on C++, what should I use on Java? (I mixed up API and Library I guess?) **(2)** But will the Android libraries be working on a Windows machine?

Comment: **(1)** As per the documentation [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) is a **desktop** *multiplatform API*. There has been an [issue raised about mobile support](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/611), but there is no resolution or timeline. See [glfm](https://github.com/brackeen/glfm) for a similar alternative. **(2)** But will the Android libraries be working on a Windows machine? Well you need to compile **your** libs for all the native devices, e.g. armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64 etc Try to build a small project on both, (*or find one from the github*), to get a feel for the Architecture.